# What's the name of this type of chart

Tags: terminology, chart-design

I'm struggling to find its name online. It's a line chart but each point of the two series are joined, as the combination of both of them is what defines each datum:

[image: Chart]

Thanks.

Comment: I would just call it a line chart with some added detail. Don't think there's a specific name for every variation in these.

Comment: looks related to a candlestick chart to me.

Comment: Hi David, Welcome to GraphicDesign.StackExchange. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as a **Range chart** or **Area Range chart**, as what defines the main data is *the range between the maximum and minimum value* and not the values independently.

As seen here https://www.highcharts.com/demo/arearange

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Range plots are a relatively new* chart type. It's an extension of the dot plot, which William Cleveland created in the 1990s. Dot plots show one or multiple dots on one line. Range plots show exactly two dots on a line and connect them with an extra bold line.

*Aug 10, 2018
How to create a range plot - Datawrapper Academy
https://academy.datawrapper.de/article/111-how-to-create-a-range-plot

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a classic Candlestick chart, in which there are three data related per period.

[D3 Candlestick Chart Page](https://bl.ocks.org/tompiler/6045b80d2164077faaf96e0304531bba)

[image]

Comment: I've created a bah-zillion candlestick charts in my career. I'd hesitate to call the sample a candlestick. The point of candle sticks is they show 3 values - entry, exit (the fat bar) and total range (the narrow bar). The sample is lacking "entry/exit" indicators and merely has the "range" indicator capped at both ends. All that being posted.. I don't know what the sample may be called specifically...."range" seems closest to me... but I could be wrong. I often am.  `:)`

Comment: I appreciate the correction Scott, and I think I agree with your supposition too - probably range is closest.

Comment: These have been called "box and whisker" plots/charts also. They're used for stock market analysis.

Answer (score -3):

No doubt, it’s a line chart, you can design this diagram in the following manner as well :

[image]

Source: https://www.slideteam.net/